# llvm-symbolizer usage in Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, llvm, llvm-clang

I am trying to use llvm-symbolizer included in Android NDK r19 beta.

I am following the man page examples [here.](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-symbolizer.html)

I am piping my valid memory, and then passing the .so file for my android ndk application. Unfortunately, all llvm-symbolizer is outputting is **??:0:0**.

```
0x001efb18 | llvm-symbolizer -pretty-print -obj=build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/MyApp.so
__cxa_atexit at ??:0:0
```

I have double checked that the memory address given in the logs is from the same build as the .so I am pointing at.

Am I am using llvm-symbolizer wrong, or is there a bug in it. Could I potentially need to pass a certain flag to the clang++ compiler when I build?